# Pandas track monthly change in price based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
part   price      date
1      67.32      2018-12-01 00:00:00.000
3      99.16      2018-12-01 00:00:00.000
1      67.32      2018-11-01 00:00:00.000
3      167.34     2018-11-01 00:00:00.000
1      67.32      2018-10-01 00:00:00.000
3      167.34     2018-10-01 00:00:00.000
1      88.37      2018-09-01 00:00:00.000
3      212.70     2018-09-01 00:00:00.000
1      88.37      2018-08-01 00:00:00.000
3      264.02     2018-08-01 00:00:00.000
1      88.37      2018-07-01 00:00:00.000
3      264.02     2018-07-01 00:00:00.000
```

I want to create a new column, call it `price_change`, that tracks how the price changes from month to month *per part*. So the above would become:

```
part   price      date                         price_change
1      67.32      2018-12-01 00:00:00.000      0.0
3      99.16      2018-12-01 00:00:00.000      -68.18
1      67.32      2018-11-01 00:00:00.000      0.0
3      167.34     2018-11-01 00:00:00.000      0.0
1      67.32      2018-10-01 00:00:00.000      -21.05
3      167.34     2018-10-01 00:00:00.000      -45.36
1      88.37      2018-09-01 00:00:00.000      0.0
3      212.70     2018-09-01 00:00:00.000      -51.32
1      88.37      2018-08-01 00:00:00.000      0.0
3      264.02     2018-08-01 00:00:00.000      0.0
1      88.37      2018-07-01 00:00:00.000      0.0
3      264.02     2018-07-01 00:00:00.000      0.0
```

In the event that the oldest date is reached, `price_change` should just be 0.

I've tried sorting and using pd.DataFrame.diff as follows:

```
df.sort_values(by=['part', 'date'])
df['price_change'] = df['price'].diff()
```

Along with fillna this almost works. The problem is that this doesn't restart the diff calculations each time a new part is reached.

Comment: Can you share the code you've written to solve your problem?

Comment: @orde I haven't solved it though. I'm hoping someone else knows how to do this.

Comment: It's possible that someone might do it for you, but the expectation is that you show your work.  Check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more info.  Good luck.

Comment: Ok, got it. I will edit my post momentarily, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `sort_values` and `groupby` then find the diff:

```
df['diff'] = df.sort_values('date').groupby('part')['price'].diff().fillna(0)

    part   price       date   diff
0      1   67.32 2018-12-01   0.00
1      3   99.16 2018-12-01 -68.18
2      1   67.32 2018-11-01   0.00
3      3  167.34 2018-11-01   0.00
4      1   67.32 2018-10-01 -21.05
5      3  167.34 2018-10-01 -45.36
6      1   88.37 2018-09-01   0.00
7      3  212.70 2018-09-01 -51.32
8      1   88.37 2018-08-01   0.00
9      3  264.02 2018-08-01   0.00
10     1   88.37 2018-07-01   0.00
11     3  264.02 2018-07-01   0.00
```